# Excel 2010 - Merging multiple rows by the value from the first row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I must find a way to merge multiple rows by the vallue from the first row.

For example the image in the following [image: link]

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. Perhaps you could expand a little on how that image is being sorted?

Answer (score 1):

The fast way to remove unwanted empty row is not by merging the cell but by deleting the empty  rows

1. Add Headings to the table,

   [image: Add headings]
2. Then apply a filter  ([Ctrl][Shift][L])

   [image: Applying a filter]
3. Filter blanks

   [image]

   like this

   [image]
4. Then delete the blank rows (select them [Ctrl][-])
5. Unfilter/ remove filter and .... Bobs your uncle

   [image]

Comment: This might not work if there are other(not shown) columns that contain data on the supposedly 'blank' rows..